# How to handle item click on list generated from ng-repeat and load next page

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, cordova

I have an html list generated using ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
  <a href="details.html">{{product.name}}</a>
</div>
```

The data for the list is obtained from a json array in my app.js in this format:

```
var items = [
   {
            "name": "Nexus 5",
            "size": "4.95 inches",
            "camera": "8 megapixels"    
   }, 
   {
            "name": "Nexus 6",
            "size": "6.0 inches",
            "camera": "13 megapixels"  
   }
];
```

I want to click on the list item and go to another page showing the respective details from the same json array. How do I do that? Have been trying to access index from the list and use it to load next page, but am unsuccessful so far. I am new to angular as well as javascript. Any intermediate steps will be very helpful.

Also, notice I am handling click on the list using an anchor tag. Is this the ideal way to do it?

Comment: I'm not well known with angularjs, but can't you save the values of an item in the attributes of the a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see for demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/qVEhc0KgKjklWCmqKJ4L?p=preview

> HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
   <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

> JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: "main.html",
    controller: "mainController"
  }).when('/detail/:productName', {
    templateUrl: "details.html",
    controller: "detailsController"
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/main"
  });
})
  .controller("mainController", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.store = {}; //.products

    $scope.store.products = dataService.getProducts();
  })
  .controller("detailsController", function($scope, $routeParams, dataService) {


    $scope.product = dataService.getProductAt($routeParams.productName);

  });


angular.module("plunker").service("dataService", function(filterFilter) {
  var items = [{
    "name": "Nexus 5",
    "size": "4.95 inches",
    "camera": "8 megapixels"
  }, {
    "name": "Nexus 6",
    "size": "6.0 inches",
    "camera": "13 megapixels"
  }];

  this.getProducts = function() {
    return items;
  };
  this.getProductAt = function(_name) {
    this.getProducts();
    return filterFilter(items, {
      name: _name
    })[0];
  };
});
```

(you need details.html and main.htm template as well)